# Problems downloading Ubuntu packages for MP4 and vlc

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mp4, vlc

I have recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu LTS and I have been trying to download  both VLC and the Ubuntu restricted extras packages, They won't install when I type sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras  , it throws an error saying it cannot locate the package.  Same with VLC.  I am so frustrated, everything I look up on how to fix this just tells me to install the restricted extras package, but my box can't find it.  Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  Never mind.  I found my problem.  It was in my software settings, I hadn't enabled the Universal option under "other software"  I seem to have fixed it now.